# What is "action at a distance" in this JEP?

Tags: java, type-inference

Here I am talking abou [this JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286). In the text, "action at a distance" is mentioned several times; for instance:

> Excluding locals with no initializers eliminates "action at a distance" inference errors, and only excludes a small portion of locals in typical programs.

or:

> Similarly, we also could have taken all assignments into account when inferring the type, rather than just the initializer; while this would have further increased the percentage of locals that could exploit this feature, it would also increase the risk of "action at a distance" errors.

I understand most of the JEP, but that part eludes me.

What is meant here by "action at a distance"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article ["Action at a distance (computer programming)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance_(computer_programming))

> In computer science, action at a distance is an anti-pattern (a
>   recognized common error) in which behavior in one part of a program
>   varies wildly based on difficult or impossible to identify operations
>   in another part of the program. The way to avoid the problems
>   associated with action at a distance are a proper design, which avoids
>   global variables and alters data in a controlled and local manner, or
>   usage of a pure functional programming style with referential
>   transparency.
>
> The term is based on the concept of action at a distance in physics,
>   which may refer to a process that allows objects to interact without a
>   mediator particle such as the gluon. In particular, Albert Einstein
>   referred to this effect in quantum mechanics as "spooky action at a
>   distance".

In this case, it refers to variables without an initializer expression, like this:

```
var list;

// many lines of code

list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

While variable type inference would be possible from an assignment expression later in the code, doing so would make the code suffer from the problems caused by "action at a distance": it would not be obvious at all to the reader of the code what the type of the local variable would be, and this could cause errors.